# How to count time in a process JNI?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

I want to make logging time which a JNI's cpp system needed for every process.This is my code :

```
/*
*  ImageProcessing.cpp
*/
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <strstream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <vector>


#define LOG_TAG "TourGuide"
#define LOGD(...) ((void)__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__))

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

std::vector<float> parse_delimeted_list_of_numbers(char* line, char delimeter)
{
    std::vector<float> vector_of_numbers;
    std::istrstream input_stream(line);
    std::string text;
    float number;
    while (std::getline(input_stream, text, delimeter)) {
        sscanf(text.c_str(), "%f", &number, text.size());
        vector_of_numbers.push_back(number);
    }
    return vector_of_numbers;
}

extern "C"
jboolean
Java_com_example_franksyesipangkar_tourguide_CameraPreview_ImageProcessing
(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray NV21FrameData, jintArray outPixels, jbyteArray b)

{

LOGD("JNIEnv");


    //convert jbyteArray to char
    jbyte *cmd = env->GetByteArrayElements(b, 0);
    LOGD("JNIEnvFeature");



    char feature[90600];//[819000] sejumlah 800kb untuk ukuran file
    memset(feature,0, sizeof(feature));
    memcpy(feature, cmd, strlen((char*)cmd));

    LOGD("OutFeature: %s", feature);
    //LOGD("OutCMD: %s", cmd);



              vector<float> vectorHOGSVM;

                vectorHOGSVM = parse_delimeted_list_of_numbers(feature, ' ');


         LOGD("Parsing Vector Success ");




    /* Mengambil data pointer */
    jbyte * pNV21FrameData = env->GetByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData, 0);
    jint * poutPixels = env->GetIntArrayElements(outPixels, 0);

    /* Membuat matrix dari input frame gambar */

    Mat mGray(height, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)pNV21FrameData);
    Mat mResult(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)poutPixels);

    /* Mengubah matrix kembali menjadi frame gambar */
    IplImage GrayImg = mGray;
    IplImage ResultImg = mResult;



        HOGDescriptor hog;
    //hog.winSize = Size(56,40);

    // Set our custom detecting vector
      hog.setSVMDetector(vectorHOGSVM);


    //hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getDefaultPeopleDetector());



    /* Deklarasi variable vector untuk menggambar kotak deteksi */
    vector<Rect> found, found_filtered;
    size_t i, j;





        hog.detectMultiScale(mGray, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);



    double t = (double)getTickCount();
    t = (double)getTickCount() - t;
   LOGD("Detection Time: %gms", t*1000./cv::getTickFrequency());
   LOGD("Animal: %d", found.size());

    for( i = 0; i < found.size(); i++ )
        {
            Rect r = found[i];
            for( j = 0; j < found.size(); j++ )
                if( j != i && (r & found[j]) == r)
                    break;
            if( j == found.size() )
                found_filtered.push_back(r);
        }
    if(found.size()) {
            Rect r = found[0];
            r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
            r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
            r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.07);
            r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.8);
            LOGD("c : %d, r : %d",r.height,r.width);



    cvCvtColor(&GrayImg, &ResultImg, CV_GRAY2BGR);



    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(NV21FrameData, pNV21FrameData, 0);
    env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(outPixels, poutPixels, 0);

    env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(b, cmd, 0);


    return true;

}
```

For detection process, I make logging time with `cv::getTickFrequency()` (OpenCV function) like this :

```
 double t = (double)getTickCount();
 t = (double)getTickCount() - t;
 LOGD("Detection Time: %gms", t*1000./cv::getTickFrequency());
```

But, in another process I don't understand for making log time.So, I want to make logging time in every process, in process `LOGD("OutFeature: %s", feature);`, and process `LOGD("Parsing Vector Success ");`.Do you have an idea for it ?

Comment: You should do some work between the two calls to `getTickCount`, or the result will be practically 0.

Comment: What do you mean @Miki ?

Comment: `double t = (double)getTickCount(); // some operations; t = (double)getTickCount() - t; LOGD(...)`

Comment: Oh..Allright @Miki..I got it